# Is Malloc safe to use with nogil?

Tags: python, c++, c, malloc, cython

Is it safe to allocate memory with malloc with nogil in cython?
Also is it safe to pass pointers with you have multithreaded program running with nogil?

Comment: Of course. As long as you free your memory when done and use locks when appropriate you're golden.

Answer (score 2):

The GIL is in place because CPythons memory management is not [thread-safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety). As a consequence, you can use `nogil` in cases where you **do not** interact with a Python Object, i.e with memory that is handled by Python.

This is mentioned in the documentation [for releasing the GIL](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#releasing-the-gil):

> Code in the body of the statement must not manipulate Python objects in any way, and must not call anything that manipulates Python objects without first re-acquiring the GIL. Cython currently does not check this.

So, using `malloc`, passing pointers and doing anything else that is legal in `C` is perfectly safe as long as no Python Objects are involved.